# Using TempData to pass html? [MVC2]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I recently discovered TempData to pass messages back to the view after processing logic in the controller. But when I try and pass html with the message it is rendering the actual tags and not interpreting them as html when the page renders.

Is there any way around this or is my approached flawed?

```
TempData["Message"] = "<span style='color:red;'>There was a problem moving the files.</span>";
```

Here is what is shown in the browser:

```
<span style='color:red;'>There was a problem moving the files.</span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're only showing one side of the problem.  The real enlightening part is the part that extracts tempdata and displays it.  Can you show that code?

Comment: Nope, TempData is what I'm using.  On the View side I was simply doing: <%: TempData["Message"]%>, but Keith had me change it to <%= TempData["Message"]%> and all is good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<%=` instead of `<%:` to process the string without decoding it.

Answer (score 12):

You can decode your html in the TempData like this:

```
@Html.Raw(TempData["Message"].ToString())
```

Comment: Alert: null reference exception

Comment: check for null first. like answer below

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be auto encoding the values; you should be able to call Server.HtmlDecode to decode it back to HTML.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You can change style in your "View" file, like this:

```
@if (TempData["Message"] != null)
     {
      <span style="color:Red;">  @TempData["Message"] </span>
}
```